# Chinese Characters are not updating/working correctly in Kolkov Angular text editor

Tags: angular

The text in Chinese language and Russian Lang characters are not saving in the correct format ( html output). please help

the Chinese characters were showing correctly in the text box but when sending/saving post response, the data is sending as special characters. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: probably you need to convert those character into UTF format before entering into the text editor.

Comment: Add some code for allowing us to analyse what exactly you are doing